# Adding image to radiobutton that can act as Toggle button using wpf

Tags: wpf, image, radio-button, togglebutton

I want to use 2 radiobuttons like a toggle button using WPF. I tried something like this:

```
<RadioButton Name="RightAnswer" Width="20">
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Image Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="{Binding Content,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                    Mode=TwoWay}"
                       ToolTip="Right Answer" />
            </ToggleButton>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
</RadioButton> 

<RadioButton Name="WrongAnswer" Width="20">
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Image Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="{Binding Content,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                    Mode=TwoWay}"
                       ToolTip="Wrong Answer" />
            </ToggleButton>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
</RadioButton>
```

I could make this work but it shows blank buttons. I want to have buttons with Image in each of them and on checked i should bind it with ViewModel code.

**Update:** I added Images in each of them which now works well. I hoping to connect the press events to VM property.

Comment: This will show blank buttons because you don't provide any images to display.

Comment: Right. I eventually added image like this, it works. Still i want to know where to bind my VM code to radiobutton/toggle button on checked.